# Last MAX report value for a given ID

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a query to select all users with their last maximum report earned. I've tried a variety of joins, but I'm either getting the first maximum report, or a user is ignored if their max report was before their last report.

For clarity, here is an example of the data I'm working with:

```
id  user_id  report_id  earned
1   20       1            55
2   20       3            30
...
7   20       3            29
8   40       3            50
9   40       3            50
10  20       3            30
11  40       3            35
...
```

I would like to select the latest highest earned report for a given report_id for all users. For the above example, the desired query would return

```
id  user_id  report_id  earned
9   40       3            50
10  20       3            30
```

However  I am getting the rows with IDs 2, 8, the first reports with the maximum earned.

Notes about the data:

- The first report is not guaranteed to have the highest earned rate
- The last report is not guaranteed to have the highest earned rate
- The first maximum is not guaranteed to be the last
- Query needs to report latest max in order to retrieve appropriate report

Any help with the problem is appreciated.

Edit:
As requested, here is a query I've tried to use (translated from the actual problem to this problem, might be some syntax errors). Honestly I've been rewriting over the same query so I don't have all my attempts.

```
SELECT
    s.id, s.user_id, s.report_id, s.earned
FROM
    submission s
JOIN user u ON s.user_id = u.id
JOIN report r ON s.report_id = r.id
JOIN (SELECT
          t.id AS ID, t.user_id, MAX(s.earned) AS MaxReport
      FROM submission t
      JOIN report r ON t.report_id = r.id
      JOIN user us ON t.user_id = us.id
      WHERE r.id = 3
      GROUP BY t.user_id
      ORDER BY ...
) BestReport ON
(s.id = BestReport.ID AND s.user_id = BestReport.user_id AND s.earned = BestReport.MaxReport
WHERE r.id = 3
```

Comment: Could you include some of the queries you have that aren't working?

Comment: I've added the last query I've tried (translated from actual problem, might have some syntax errors)

Comment: How do you define *latest report*?

Comment: Latest report would be the last report added for a given user. The accepted answer worked for me though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
select max(s.id) id, s.user_id, s.report_id, s.earned from (
  select user_id, report_id, max(earned) maxearned
  from submission
  group by user_id, report_id
) g inner join submission s
on s.user_id = g.user_id and s.report_id = g.report_id and s.earned = g.maxearned
group by s.user_id, s.report_id, s.earned
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wp8JT9ZRgqtrj6PJfBDyB/0)
If you want a query only for `report_id = 3`:

```
select max(s.id) id, s.user_id, s.report_id, s.earned from (
  select user_id, report_id, max(earned) maxearned
  from submission
  where report_id = 3
  group by user_id, report_id
) g inner join submission s
on s.user_id = g.user_id and s.report_id = g.report_id and s.earned = g.maxearned
group by s.user_id, s.report_id, s.earned
order by id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wp8JT9ZRgqtrj6PJfBDyB/3)

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I'm too new to give a vote, I'll come back to this post when I have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a higher id means a more recent report (Storing a timestamp would be better), you can use window functions on recent versions of sqlite to simplify things a lot:

```
SELECT id, user_id, report_id, earned
FROM (SELECT id, user_id, report_id, earned
           , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY report_id, user_id ORDER BY earned DESC, id DESC) AS ranking
      FROM example)
WHERE ranking=1 AND report_id=3;
id          user_id     report_id   earned    
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
10          20          3           30        
9           40          3           50
```